# How can I change the way TensorFlow performs addition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have designed a new method to do additions that returns "approximately" correct results (i.e. it outputs a rough estimate of the actual sum). I want to quantify the effect of approximating addition this way on the accuracy of neural network inference.

I found a TensorFlow implementation of a neural network whose accuracy I want to assess ([MobileNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet)). I want to be run inference on various examples using this network - *however*, I want this network to perform any of it's necessary additions *using my approximate addition method*.

In other words, anytime the network tries to perform an addition, I want the addition to be done using my approximate add operation instead.

I found [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op) that describes how to create your own TensorFlow operation. I can use this to implement my approximate addition operation.

**What's the easiest way for me to "convert" all additions in the existing MobileNet implementation to use my approximate addition instead?**

It's not as simple as copy and pasting over all instances of `tf.add` unfortunately. Additions are used all over the place, from ReLU operations, to `conv2d` layers, and I need to make sure that all additions used in the inference are done using my adder instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a workaround for your problem. Basically, navigate to the source code of the `tf.add` method. If you're on TF 2.0, it should be in the `tf.math` module. It looks like,

```
@_dispatch.add_dispatch_list
@tf_export('math.add', 'add')
def add(x, y, name=None):
  r"""Returns x + y element-wise.

  *NOTE*: `math.add` supports broadcasting. `AddN` does not. More about broadcasting
  [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

  Args:
    x: A `Tensor`. Must be one of the following types: `bfloat16`, `half`, `float32`, `float64`, `uint8`, `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, `complex64`, `complex128`, `string`.
    y: A `Tensor`. Must have the same type as `x`.
    name: A name for the operation (optional).

  Returns:
    A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `x`.
  """
  _ctx = _context._context or _context.context()
  if _ctx is not None and _ctx._thread_local_data.is_eager:
    try:
      _result = _pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
        _ctx._context_handle, _ctx._thread_local_data.device_name, "Add",
        name, _ctx._post_execution_callbacks, x, y)
      return _result
    except _core._FallbackException:
      try:
        return add_eager_fallback(
            x, y, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
      except _core._SymbolicException:
        pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
      except (TypeError, ValueError):
        result = _dispatch.dispatch(
              add, x=x, y=y, name=name)
        if result is not _dispatch.OpDispatcher.NOT_SUPPORTED:
          return result
        raise
    except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
      if name is not None:
        message = e.message + " name: " + name
      else:
        message = e.message
      _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  try:
    _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
        "Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  except (TypeError, ValueError):
    result = _dispatch.dispatch(
          add, x=x, y=y, name=name)
    if result is not _dispatch.OpDispatcher.NOT_SUPPORTED:
      return result
    raise
  _result = _op.outputs[:]
  _inputs_flat = _op.inputs
  _attrs = ("T", _op._get_attr_type("T"))
  _execute.record_gradient(
      "Add", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result, name)
  _result, = _result
  return _result
```

The method takes in two tensors and returns their sum. You can apply your addition method here. All other ops in TensorFlow, at their core, will use this method to add two tensors.
You will require to understand this method and also to record the gradients needed at the time of optimization.

> I had the edited the source code for Leaky ReLU in `tf.nn.relu`. `tf.math.add()` is a fundamental op, therefore make sure that you implement your method properly.

Comment: You can find the .py file [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py).

Comment: Thanks! Does TensorFlow guarantee that *all* operations use `tf.add` for *all* additions?

Comment: No. TensorFlow does not make such a guarantee. You can open up some other TF method and check which op it uses.